# Using Alertdialog.Builder when I press a image view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

When I open my fragment it contains 10 imageViews and when I long click on every imageView it plays 4 audios and popups alert box when 1st audio`s completed 2nd will play and so up to 5th. When 5th audio completed dialog will dismiss.

```
case R.id.pg10_3: {

            final AlertDialog.Builder mbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            View mview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.page10_popup, null);


            p10tajweed_letter = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.tajweed_heading);
            p10first_letter_a = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.p10_1la_pop);
            p10first_letter_b = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.p10_1lb_pop);
            p10first_letter_c = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.p10_1lc_pop);
            p10first_letter_d = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.p10_1ld_pop);
            p10first_letter_e = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.p10_1le_pop);
            disable = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.p10_1lf_pop);
            p10first_letter_a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            p10first_letter_b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            p10first_letter_c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            p10first_letter_d.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            p10first_letter_e.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            p10tajweed_letter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            mbuilder.setView(mview);
            final AlertDialog dialog = mbuilder.create();
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp1.stop();
                    mp2.stop();
                    mp3.stop();
                    mp4.stop();
                    mp5.stop();
                }
            });


            if (mp.isPlaying() || mp1.isPlaying() || mp2.isPlaying() || mp3.isPlaying() || mp4.isPlaying() || mp5.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
                mp1.stop();
                mp2.stop();
                mp3.stop();
                mp4.stop();
                mp5.stop();
                clearcolor();
            }
            try {
                if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 0 && UtilityMethods.GetPreferences("check", getActivity()) == false) {
                    try {
                        if (mp.isPlaying() || mp1.isPlaying() || mp2.isPlaying() || mp3.isPlaying() || mp4.isPlaying() || mp5.isPlaying()) {
                            mp.stop();
                            mp1.stop();
                            mp2.stop();
                            mp3.stop();
                            mp4.stop();
                            mp5.stop();
                            clearcolor();
                        }
                        mp.reset();
                        p10first_letter_a.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q1p10_1la.mp3");
                        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            p10first_letter_a.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
                            p10first_letter_b.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            mp1.reset();
                            try {
                                if (mp.isPlaying() || mp1.isPlaying() || mp2.isPlaying() || mp3.isPlaying() || mp4.isPlaying() || mp5.isPlaying()) {
                                    mp.stop();
                                    mp1.stop();
                                    mp2.stop();
                                    mp3.stop();
                                    mp4.stop();
                                    mp5.stop();
                                    clearcolor();
                                }
                                mp1.reset();
                                afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q1p10_1lb.mp3");
                                mp1.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                                mp1.prepare();
                                mp1.start();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            p10first_letter_b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#32CD32"));
                            p10first_letter_c.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            p10first_letter_d.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            try {
                                if (mp.isPlaying() || mp1.isPlaying() || mp2.isPlaying() || mp3.isPlaying() || mp4.isPlaying() || mp5.isPlaying()) {
                                    mp.stop();
                                    mp1.stop();
                                    mp2.stop();
                                    mp3.stop();
                                    mp4.stop();
                                    mp5.stop();
                                    clearcolor();
                                }
                                mp2.reset();
                                afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q1p10_1lc.mp3");
                                mp2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                                mp2.prepare();
                                mp2.start();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            p10first_letter_c.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff1521"));
                            p10first_letter_d.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));
                            p10first_letter_e.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            try {
                                if (mp.isPlaying() || mp1.isPlaying() || mp2.isPlaying() || mp3.isPlaying() || mp4.isPlaying() || mp5.isPlaying()) {
                                    mp.stop();
                                    mp1.stop();
                                    mp2.stop();
                                    mp3.stop();
                                    mp4.stop();
                                    mp5.stop();
                                    clearcolor();
                                }
                                mp3.reset();
                                afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q1p10_1ld.mp3");
                                mp3.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                                mp3.prepare();
                                mp3.start();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    mp3.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            p10first_letter_e.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#32CD32"));
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Here is my 1st imagView long click listener code. The problem is when I click first time on any imageView and immediately touch outside the alert dialog, dialog dismisses but remaining audios play and when I repeat this again dialog dismiss and audios stop. What is happening with first time ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line:

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Comment: i need to stop audio when clicked outside the dialog box but unfortunately first audios did not stop but when i click second time it stops. what is happening first time why audios are playing

Comment: Try this `if(!dialog.isShowing()){ mp1.stop(); }` or whatever mp you want to stop.

Comment: the piece of code i used is working perfectly but when i long press 2nd time in a fragment but first time i click outside it plays the remaining audios.

Comment: Try defining your builder and dialog outside the switch/case and make sure you're stopping all the mp's with the like so `if(!dialog.isShowing()){ 
mp.stop(); 
mp1.stop();
mp2.stop();
mp3.stop();
mp4.stop();
mp5.stop;
}`

Comment: i tried defining builder outside but not working and on cancel dialog i stop all media player instances. why first time its not working fine as when i click again

Comment: I don't know sorry, does your app crash after couple of times doing that or it works after first time not working the way it should ?

Comment: it works perfectly after first time like it stops every media player instance but first time it does not stops

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to calling `mediaPlayerObj.prepare()`.
Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#preparingasync):

> **The call to prepare() can take a long time to execute**, because it
>   might involve fetching and decoding media data

Your dialog is shown prior to calling `prepare()`. As soon as you click outside of dialog, dialog is cancelled and tries to `stop()` media player.
Based on the documentation for `mediaPalyerObj.stop()`:

> Stops playback after playback has been **started or paused**.

Since your player is busy in preparing the audio, it doesn't "start" immediately. As a result, your `onstop()`does nothing.

But during second time, your media player has already started the audio and `stop()` method will be effective again.

Looking at your code, the audio is bundled with apk. Put it in `res/raw/` instead of assests.

If your audio is available as local raw resource (res/raw/), then you don't have to call the `prepare()`.

> A "raw" resource is a file that the system does not try to parse in
>   any particular way.

You can refer official document [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer).